# trying to get the delta between columns using FasterCSV

Tags: ruby, arrays, include, fastercsv

A bit of a noob here so apologies in advance.

I am trying to read a CSV file which has a number of columns, I would like see if one string  "foo" exists anywhere in the file, and if so, grab the string one cell over (aka same row, one column over) and then write that to a file

my file c.csv:

```
foo,bar,yip
12,apple,yap
23,orange,yop
foo,tom,yum
```

so in this case, I would want "bar" and "tom" in a new csv file.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby -w

require 'rubygems'
require 'fastercsv'

rows = FasterCSV.read("c.csv")
acolumn = rows.collect{|row| row[0]}

if acolumn.select{|v| v =~ /foo/} == 1
i = 0
for z in i..(acolumn).count
puts rows[1][i]
end
```

I've looked here https://github.com/circle/fastercsv/blob/master/examples/csv_table.rb but I am obviously not understanding it, my best guess is that I'd have to use Table to do what I want to do but after banging my head up against the wall for a bit, I decided to ask for advice from the experienced folks.  help please?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  Can you please add a short example with two input files and the corresponding two output files?

Comment: Hi Wayne - thanks in advance, have updated my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your input file *c.csv*

```
foo,bar,yip
12,apple,yap
23,orange,yop
foo,tom,yum
```

then this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

require 'fastercsv'

FasterCSV.open('output.csv', 'w') do |output|
  FasterCSV.foreach('c.csv') do |row|
    foo_index = row.index('foo')
    if foo_index
      value_to_the_right_of_foo = row[foo_index + 1]
      output << value_to_the_right_of_foo
    end
  end
end
```

will create the file *output.csv*

```
bar
tom
```

Comment: @MarkL I'm pleased that it works for you.  Thanks for the question!